# pgp_sym_decrypt key error when decrypting

Tags: postgresql-14

I am trying to use a symmetric key to encrypt and decrypt a field in Postgres 14.10.

I am encrypting per documentation like so:

```
select pgp_sym_encrypt('data', 'password');
```

I am feeding the return of the above into decrypt data:

```
select pgp_sym_decrypt_bytea('0xC30D04090302F39E612C4A8DD96974D23A011F61B98966A502BC5354962D9B34E5EA3963A347E01B19FC334E7B2FF716978BD74EE4322DBEC4E2118E4AAB471A54D76EDEA25309287095A5', 'password');
```

The error is `[39000] ERROR: Wrong key or corrupt data`

I have tried specifying options such as `'compress-algo=1, cipher-algo=aes256'` and casting the encrypted data as `::bytea`, but I always get the same error.

How can I encrypt and decrypt with a symmetric key?